# Java Spring, erro ao autenticar com active diretory

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, active-directory

Iai pessoal, em minha empresa implementamos um ambiente de active diretory, e nos foi solicitado desenvolver uma aplicação que se autenticasse por lá, o ambiente já esta criado e o cara da infra me mandou os parametros para que o acesso possa ser realizado porém ao tentar me autenticar com um usuário de teste que sei que existe, eu recebo uma exceção que não consigo entender, peço que me ajudem.
Esta é minha classe de configuração:

```
@Configuration
public class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

//Parametros vindos do time de infra
public static final String ip = "00.0.000.000";
public static final String dominio = "teste.com.br";
public static final int porta = 389;
public static final String queryBase = "DC=teste,DC=com,DC=br";
public static final String queryParaUsuarios = "CN=Users," + queryBase;
public static final String usuarioAdministrador = "admUser";
public static final String password = "*****";
public static final String dnDoAdministrador = "CN=" + usuarioAdministrador + "," + queryParaUsuarios;

@Autowired
private UserService userDetailContext;

@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.ldapAuthentication()
            .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailContext)
            .userDnPatterns("cn={0}," + queryParaUsuarios)
            .contextSource()
            .root(queryBase)
            .url("ldap://" + ip).port(porta);
    }
}
```

E este é o erro que recebo sempre que tento me autenticar:

```
org.springframework.ldap.UncategorizedLdapException: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00002020: Operation unavailable without authentication]; remaining name ''
at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:228) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:397) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:328) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:629) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:570) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForMultipleAttributeValues(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:241) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.searchForSingleAttributeValues(SpringSecurityLdapTemplate.java:166) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGroupMembershipRoles(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:241) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.getGrantedAuthorities(DefaultLdapAuthoritiesPopulator.java:210) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider.loadUserAuthorities(LdapAuthenticationProvider.java:213) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractLdapAuthenticationProvider.java:89) ~[spring-security-ldap-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:174) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:180) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 00002020: Operation unavailable without authentication]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3194) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3100) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2891) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.searchAux(LdapCtx.java:1846) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.c_search(LdapCtx.java:1769) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.ComponentDirContext.p_search(ComponentDirContext.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:358) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.ctx.PartialCompositeDirContext.search(PartialCompositeDirContext.java:341) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext.search(InitialDirContext.java:267) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate$4.executeSearch(LdapTemplate.java:322) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate.search(LdapTemplate.java:363) ~[spring-ldap-core-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
... 53 common frames omitted
```